# Ignoring null values in join SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join

I need to fetch details from Table 2, based on the inputs in Table 1.
There can be null values in Table 1, but the null inputs needs to be ignored in the comparison when doing join to Table2

For example - The output should include all papers belonging to the subject if paper is null in Table1.
Can you suggest a way I could ignore nulls in joins? Query needs to be in SQL Server

```
ID  Paper   Subject Department
------------------------------
1   paper1  Math    Dept1
2   null    Math    Dept1
3   null    null    Dept2
4   paper4  Science Dept2
```

Table2

```
Paper   Subject Department  details1    details2    details3
paper1  Math    Dept1        D1          D2          D3
paper2  Math    Dept1        D1          D2          D3
Paper1  Science Dept2        D1          D2          D3
Paper2  Science Dept2        D1          D2          D3
Paper3  Science Dept1        D1          D2          D3
Paper4  Science Dept2        D1          D2          D3
```

output

```
 Paper  Subject Department  Details1    Details2    Details3
 paper1 Math    Dept1       D1          D2          D3
 paper2 Math    Dept1       D1          D2          D3
 Paper1 Science Dept2       D1          D2          D3
 Paper2 Science Dept2       D1          D2          D3
 paper4 Science Dept2       D1          D2          D3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in the logic? because in table2 there is `3xDept1` and `3xDept2` but your output only get `2xDept1` when `Dept2` is the one with more nulls.

Comment: Also looks like `details` isn't relevant for the query because all are the same, you should remove it from the question to make it simple.  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Paper 3, Science, Dept1 will not be part of output since Table1 does have such input condition.   But all three records of Dept2 will be in output as Table 1 has null for paper and subject for one record. The output should be driven by the values in the Table 1.

Comment: Again can you explain what is `input condition`? I don't see `Paper2` or `Paper3` in Table1. Cant understand why one show and the other doesn't.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: All details from Table 2 should be fetched which are matched to the values in Table1, ignoring nulls in the matching condition.  For ID 2 in Table1, since Paper is null, the output should contain all records with subject Math and Dept1, for ID 3 since paper and subject are null, all records with Dept2 should be fetched

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM @table2 a
INNER JOIN @table1 b
ON a.[Paper] = b.[Paper] 
OR (b.[Paper] IS NULL AND b.[Subject] = a.[Subject] AND b.[Department] = a.[Department])
OR (b.[Paper] IS NULL AND b.[Subject] IS NULL AND b.[Department] = a.[Department])
ORDER BY a.[Subject]
```

Comment: Yes, this is the query. Thank you.  I tried doing or in the join, but I missed to add null check b.[Paper] IS NULL which didn't give me proper results. Your query is perfect.

Comment: Great! Glad i could help.